# Is there any way to create a bar chart with multiple ranges in same row?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I need to make bar chart with multiple ranges in same row.

[image]

[This is an example](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/timeline-charts/advanced/)

My problem is that I need Xaxis in integer type not 'datetime' as it is in this example. When I change Xaxis type to integer chart does not show as I want it because there will be created for every range new column.

[image]

This is my output:

```
    var options = {
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Bob',
            data: [
                {
                    x: 'Design',
                    y: [
                        4,9
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Code',
                    y: [
                        5,7
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Code',
                    y: [
                        0,1
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Test',
                    y: [
                        9,10
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Test',
                    y: [
                        4,7
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Validation',
                    y: [
                        2,5
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Design',
                    y: [
                        1,2
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [
                {
                    x: 'Design',
                    y: [
                        1,2
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Test',
                    y: [
                        4,6
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Code',
                    y: [
                        7,9
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Deployment',
                    y: [
                        1,5
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Design',
                    y: [
                        4,7
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Dan',
            data: [
                {
                    x: 'Code',
                    y: [
                        3,5
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Validation',
                    y: [
                        2,3
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    chart: {
        height: 450,
        type: 'rangeBar'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: true,
            barHeight: '80%'
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10
    },
    stroke: {
        width: 1
    },
    fill: {
        type: 'solid',
        opacity: 0.6
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'top',
        horizontalAlign: 'left'
    }
};
```

This is my code. In other words I need to have for example for 'Bob' in 'Design' two bars. One in range 1-2 and second in range 4-9. Is it even possible with apexcharts?

Comment: Found anything?